# How do I escalate a security concern of a library when the author doesn't seem to care

Tags: opensource, disclosure

There's an open source library that is horribly insecure. The author acknowledges it's insecure. The library's headline says "This is an implementation for platform X of Library Y". Library Y is secure therefore the headline that his library is an implementation of a secure library Y strongly suggests his implementation is also secure. Nowhere does his library or it's readme and docs ever mention it is insecure.

I politely brought it up, enumerated the issues, and politely suggested he add a warning to the readme. He said he didn't think anyone would think his library is secure. I pointed out he claims his library is an implementation of Y and Y is known to be designed to be secure. He responded he saw my point and suggested I sent a pull request to update the readme. I did. That was 12 months ago. Others have brought it up but no movement.

Let me also add his library is not actually an implementation of Y. It's similar but would need months of work to actually pass Y's conformance tests and so on top of being insecure it's also effectively lying about being an implementation of Y.

What if anything should I say that might encourage movement? My gut (which I know is wrong) is to basically say he's a jerk for misleading people and putting people at risk and that he should really take the issue more seriously. It's not the most popular library but according to at least one distro point it's been downloaded 160 times this month and there are a few dependent libraries. Assuming that's an average per month then up to 1920 people/projects are at risk.

Comment: It's not the library author's responsibility to monitor how their library is used. If it's potentially insecure, don't use it. If someone else uses it and they face problems, then they learn a lesson about using other people's open source code. If you care that much, fork the project yourself, and update it as you see fit, and point other people to your fork.

Comment: @gman Why not at least post a comment on the repository, mentioning your concerns? It might encourage other users to explore the issue

Answer (score 5):

The author obviously does not consider their project a priority anymore. That's not uncommon. There are too many interesting problems in the world and too little time to solve them all, so projects tend to become abandoned. This includes projects with known security problems. All you can do is make people aware that this piece of software is insecure.

- Report the vulnerabilities to the [NIST Vulnerability Database](https://www.nist.gov/programs-projects/national-vulnerability-database-nvd).
- Does the project have a public bugtracker? Then you should report the security vulnerabilities as bugs. People who evaluate open source software they consider using usually check the bugtracker to get an impression of how well maintained it is. Multiple open bugs regarding critical security flaws will usually be a huge red flag.
- Contact dependent projects directly that the library they are using has serious flaws they might not be aware of.

When you feel altruistic, you could fix the problems yourself. Send in a patch or do a pull request when it's on GitHub. When the author completely lost interest, you might want to suggest to take it from them and become the official maintainer. When the author is completely uncooperative, you could start a fork.

Answer (score -4):

Generally, when the vender does not respond appropriately, you publicly disclose the vulnerabilities. You can post it on Exploit-db or something.

Comment: ... while following responsible disclosure guidelines, of course, right?

Comment: To make this a good answer, you might want to elaborate on the "or something". Exploit-DB would not be my first choice, because its mostly about posting working exploits, not just vulnerabilities one *might* exploit. Sure, having a working exploit is the best proof that the vulnerability you talk about is actually there. But putting an exploit online before following responsible disclosure is irresponsible.

Comment: "or something"? That seems a little vague. Considering the original source of the question (interpersonal skills), the OP might need a little more guidance than that.

Comment: I would recommend posting to full-disclosure on seclists instead. As said above, exploit-db has a different purpose.